# Apps Script bot for webhooks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I'm looking to see if anyone has created a chatbot in google apps script to handle webhooks for hangouts? I have a bot created but I'm not sure on how to input the webhook url into the bots code so that the message can be deployed into the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

I have not exactly created what you are looking for, however I believe the answer you are looking for can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script). Basically there is an event whenever your bot enters a space. When that event is triggered you can add the space id to a list stored somewhere.(Spreadsheet , PropertiesService,etc)

Once the list is stored you can deploy your application as a web app. You can read more about web apps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) but two things you need to know is google gives you a url to make web requests to, as well as pair of events called doGet (when someone makes a get request) and doPost (when someone makes a post request). You can create the function do post and get the parameters when your web app is posted to.

Finally upon receiving the post you can do a fetch call to the google api to post the message you just received from the request to all of the spaces you are in by doing a api fetch call to each ID.

Below will be code directly posted from the API in the first link.

```
// Example bot for Hangouts Chat that demonstrates bot-initiated messages
// by spamming the user every minute.
//
// This bot makes use of the Apps Script OAuth2 library at:
//     https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2
//
// Follow the instructions there to add the library to your script.

// When added to a space, we store the space's ID in ScriptProperties.
function onAddToSpace(e) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
      .setProperty(e.space.name, '');
  return {
    'text': 'Hi! I\'ll post a message here every minute. ' +
            'Please remove me after testing or I\'ll keep spamming you!'
  };
}

// When removed from a space, we remove the space's ID from ScriptProperties.
function onRemoveFromSpace(e) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
      .deleteProperty(e.space.name);
}

// Add a trigger that invokes this function every minute via the 
// "Edit > Current Project's Triggers" menu. When it runs, it will
// post in each space the bot was added to.
function onTrigger() {
  var spaceIds = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
      .getKeys();
  var message = { 'text': 'Hi! It\'s now ' + (new Date()) };
  for (var i = 0; i < spaceIds.length; ++i) {
    postMessage(spaceIds[i], message);
  }
}
var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot';
// The values below are copied from the JSON file downloaded upon
// service account creation.
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE 
KEY-----\n';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'service-account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com';

// Posts a message into the given space ID via the API, using
// service account authentication.
function postMessage(spaceId, message) {
  var service = OAuth2.createService('chat')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setPrivateKey(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setClientId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope(SCOPE);
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
   Logger.log('Authentication error: %s', service.getLastError());
    return;
  }
  var url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/' + spaceId + '/messages';
   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(message),
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, seems like a lot to do just to enable webhook's to work in hangout's chat, while with slack i can just grab the add-on and I'm set.