# How to access script properties from another GAS project

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on Google Apps Script.

I have two GAS projects. One has data set in the script property. I want to read the property value from another GAS project.

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Script Properties are not shareable between projects.

Comment: Why not move the data to document properties or just another sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done directly but it's possible if you create an API for the script project holding the script property by using `doPost` and calling if from the other project by using `UrlFetchApp`

Many could qualify the above as an over-engineered solution as it is simpler to use a spreadsheet as a "properties" store.

Related

- [How to use ContentService and doPost to create a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935420/1595451)
- [How To Use Appscript doPost to create a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034140/1595451)
- [Apps Script bot for webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54149179/1595451)